# Combining Tables in MySQL to replace NULL values when rows match

Tags: mysql, sql, case-when

I have an issue where different pieces of information on customers are found in completely different servers.

My solution so far is to take the necessary pieces from each server and combine them in MySQL.

My problem:
I'm looking to replace NULL values from one table in MySQL with information from another table when NULL in the first table, provided other columns match.

Information will only appear in the second table when the columns appear as NULL in the OrderName column and -1 in the Order_ID column from the original table. This second table will have the missing information and will align with other columns such as Cust_ID and DateTime.

E.g.

Table1:

```
Cust_ID    |   Order_ID    |    OrderName    |    DateTime    |    Other_Info
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345      |      -1       |      NULL       |   2016/01/01   |      Info1
12345      |     1254      |     Orange      |   2016/02/03   |      Info2
54321      |     5412      |     Apple       |   2016/04/15   |      Info3
45899      |      -1       |      NULL       |   2016/06/08   |      Info4
```

Table2:

```
Cust_ID    |    OrderID    |    OrderName    |    DateTime
-------------------------------------------------------------
12345      |     1549      |     Banana      |   2016/01/01
45899      |     5862      |     Grape       |   2016/06/08
```

Desired output:

```
Cust_ID    |   Order_ID    |    OrderName    |    DateTime    |    Other_Info
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345      |     1549      |     Banana      |   2016/01/01   |      Info1
12345      |     1254      |     Orange      |   2016/02/03   |      Info2
54321      |     5412      |     Apple       |   2016/04/15   |      Info3
45899      |     5862      |     Grape       |   2016/06/08   |      Info4
```

I have tried using *CASE WHEN* clauses combined with *COALESCE* function to achieve this with no success as of yet.

Is this possible to do in MySQL?

If so, any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: plz remove unneeded tags like `sql-server`

Comment: Why do you have two so similar tables? Can't you store all data in table1 and drop table2?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `left join`:

```
select t1.cust_id, coalesce(t2.orderid, t1.order_id) as order_id,
       coalesce(t2.order_name, t1.order_name) as order_name,
       t1.datetime, t1.other_info
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id and
        t1.datetime = t2.datetime and
        t1.order_id = -1;
```

Comment: @sagi . . . `COALESCE()` will work fine.  The problem was in the `ON` clause clause; the proper comparison is there now for matching between the tables.  The `NULL` comes from the `LEFT JOIN` not matching.

Comment: Oh yea, I see what you were doing now :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE EXPRESSION` with a `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT t1.cust_id,
       CASE WHEN t1.order_id = -1 THEN t2.orderid else t1.order_id END as order_id,
       CASE WHEN t1.orderName IS NULL THEN t2.orderName else t1.orderName END as order_Name,
       t1.dateTime,
       t1.other_info
FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN Table2 s
 ON(t.cust_id = s.cust_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

**LEFT JOIN with CASE condition can get your required data.**

```
 SELECT T1.CUST_ID,
    CASE WHEN T1.ORDER_NAME IS NULL THEN T2.ORDER_ID ELSE T1.ORDER_ID END, 
    CASE WHEN T1.ORDER_NAME IS NULL THEN T2.ORDER_NAME ELSE T1.ORDER_NAME END, 
    T1._DATE_TIME,
    T1.OTHER_INFO
    FROM
    TABLE1 T1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.CUST_ID = T2.CUST_ID;
```